# How to remove elements from vector in the cycle in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, erase

I have 2 vectors of double: `t` and `P`. Their size is `m`.

I want to check the condition: `|t[i]-t[i+1]| < dT` for vector `t` and `|P[i]-P[i+1]| < dP` for vector `P`.

Then if condition is correct, I should delete `t[i+1]` element (or `P[i+1]` element).

My code:

```
//fill vectors
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < t.size() - 1; i++)
    if (abs(t[i] - t[i + 1]) < dT)
        t.erase(t.begin() + (i + 1));


for (unsigned int j = 0; j < p.size() - 1; j++)
    if (abs(p[j] - p[j + 1]) < dP)
        p.erase(p.begin() + (j + 1));
```

Is it the right way when I delete by index using `erase`?

Comment: Use the [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) function as part of the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a task it is better to use standard algorithm `std::unique` with a predicate and then to apply the member function `erase` to the returned iterator.

As for your code then it is invalid. You should not increase the index when an element is erased.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the algorithm `std::unqiue` can be used

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 1, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 5 };
    const double delta = 1.0;

    for ( const auto &x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    v.erase( 
        std::unique( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                     [&]( const auto &x, const auto &y ) 
                     { 
                        return ::abs( x - y ) < delta; 
                     } ),
        v.end() );


    for ( const auto &x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 1.5 3 4.5 5 
1 3 4.5
```

Comment: Why when I change `unique` to `remove_if` there's two errors in lamba function? It says about wrong written arguments?

Error C2780 'auto main::operator ()(const _T1 &,const _T2 &) const': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided 

Error C2672 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: @EmilSakhibgareev  remove_if passes only one argument to predicate. So it is std::unique that is more appropriate for such a task.